# kotlin smart cast doesn't work if condition check in the other function

Tags: kotlin

For example:

```
fun test() {
    val s: String? = ""
    check(s != null)

    // Error: Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?
    s.subSequence(0, 1)
}

inline fun check(expression: Boolean) {
    if (!expression) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }
}
```

The `check` function is `inline`, so it is same as:

```
fun test() {
    val s: String? = ""
    //check(s != null)
    if (!(s != null)) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }

    // It worked!
    s.subSequence(0, 1)
}
```

By the way, even use contract, `!= null` is OK, but `!== null` still failed

Comment: You have to use the contracts, tell to that to the compiler.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu contract doesn't work when use `!==`

Answer (score 5):

If you use the built-in [`check()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check.html) function (which throws `IllegalStateException`), instead of your own custom one, it works fine.

If you want `IllegalArgumentException`, you can use [`require()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html).

You can make the compiler smart-cast on custom functions if you use the [`@ExperimentalContracts`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.contracts/-experimental-contracts/) attribute and add a [`contract`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.contracts/contract.html):

```
@ExperimentalContracts
fun test() {
    val s: String? = ""
    myCheck(s != null)

    s.subSequence(0, 1) // smart cast
}

@ExperimentalContracts
inline fun myCheck(expression: Boolean) {
    contract {
        returns() implies expression
    }
    if (!expression) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a bug, but documented limitation. [implies] function can accept only a subset of boolean expressions, including null-checks (== null, != null), but excluding referencial equality check.

Comment: @МихаилНафталь result of `x !== null` is a `Boolean`, not a `Boolean?`, `Boolean` is fit to `implies`

Comment: It is Boolean, but it is not enough. See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.contracts/-simple-effect/implies.html

Comment: @МихаилНафталь See the first condition: "true of false checks, in case if the parameter or receiver is Boolean". `!==` means: `val bool = (x !=== nul)`, this is a "true of false checks". Maybe kotlin optimized some special conditon (such as != null), but, without optimization, `!==` should be permitted. I think this is a bug.

Comment: receiver here (`this`) is not `Boolean`, it is `String?`

Comment: @МихаилНафталь thanks for the link. It is indeed strange that the type of `booleanExpression` is `Boolean`, but there is actually more going on than the type system can express, especially as `if (foo !== null) {...}` does smart-cast `foo`.

Comment: [While Kotlin contracts look promising, the current syntax is unstable at the moment, and it's possible that it will be completely changed in the future.](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-contracts)